# The inequality of inversibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ a $n\times n$ real Matrix  such that : 
\[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,i})^{2} > (n-1) (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j}^{2})\] , prove that $rank(A)=n$ . (i.e $det(A)\neq 0$ ) .
the inequality can be seen as : \[ Tr(~^{t}A)  Tr(A) > (n-1) Tr(~^{t}AA) \]

Answer (score 1):

$Tr(A)=\sum_1^n{\lambda_i},Tr(A'A)=\sum_1^n{\lambda_i^2}$

So $(\sum_1^n{\lambda_i})^2>(n-1)\sum_1^n{\lambda_i^2}$

if $\exists j, s.t. \lambda_j=0$, we have:

$(\sum_1^n{\lambda_i})^2>(n-1)\sum_1^n{\lambda_i^2}=(n-1)\sum_{i\neq j}{\lambda_i^2}\geq(\sum_{i\neq j}{\lambda_i})^2=(\sum_1^n{\lambda_i})^2$

This is a contradiction.

Comment: your proof would be correct if the $\lambda_{i}$ are real , which is not necessary the case